# Capturing the Desktop wallpaper in the background of the Activity

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to create an Android App which captures the current wallpaper of Device Desktop, in the background. Which is already done in an App which is shown below in images. as:

[image]

**Desktop of Device:**

**And Background of an Clock App:**

[image]

So, My problem is the same as above, how we set the background of an Activity as the current Desktop WallPaper. Please suggest me the right solution about the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you capturing the wallpaper or entire screen of device ?? The images you shown here are only whole screen captures not wallpaper captures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if current system has wallpaper, you use [`peekDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#peekDrawable%28%29):

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager1 = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable1 = wallpaperManager1.peekDrawable();
```

And Implement it like this:

```
if (wallpaperDrawable1==null)
{                       
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable1=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg1);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable1);

}
else
{
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable1);
}
```

Comment: wallpaperManager1 should be the object of WallPaperManager Class but this is the anonymous class, how to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

set for your activity in the manifest file :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"
```

it will work even if the wallpaper is a live one